# How can I change classes on click of php generated elements?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<tr>
    <td>Guinea-Bissau</td>
    <td>1151330</td>
    <td>36120</td>
    <td>
        <span class='show-more' onclick='showReligion(79)' id="79">Show more
        <i class='material-icons icon'>add</i></span>

        <div class='show-more-retracted'>
            Christian<br>
            Muslim<br>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I generate html, with php, like the one above and I want to change the class of the div.show-more-retracted element to show-more-expanded, when I click "show more"/the "add" icon.

The Id's are also generated and I give the Id as an argument to the showReligion() function and that works, since I checked it with console.log.

I tried it with

```
function showReligion(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(toString(id));
    element.classList.toggle("show-more-expanded");
}
```

I always got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')`

I realized that this code would only change the class of the span element where the "Show more" is located in.

How can I change the class from "show-more-retracted" to "show-more-expanded"?

Comment: There's no `toString()` function in JavaScript. It's just `String()`. But you don't even need that, `getElementById()` will automatically convert the argument to a string.

Comment: BTW, you have `id="79"` on the wrong element. It should be on the div, not the span.

Answer (score 0):

`.nextElementSibling` to get next element and `.className` to get/set the class

```
function showReligion(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.nextElementSibling.className ="show-more-expanded";
}
```

to toggle between `show-more-retracted` and `show-more-expanded`

```
function showReligion(id) {
  var element = document.getElementById(id).nextElementSibling;
  var newClass = element.className.includes("retracted") ? "show-more-expanded" : "show-more-retracted";
  element.className = newClass;
}
```